# How to pass a value of a UserControls Textbox into a different Usercontrols Textbox with a buttonclick?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My Problem is that, i want to pass a Textbox value from a UserControl (FirstUsercontrol into a different UserControls Textbox (SecondUsercontrol) when the user clicks a Button on the FirstUserControl .
I've searched alot on the Internet and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747702/binding-a-property-with-another-property-owned-to-a-user-control).

However, my problem still exists and i really dont know how to solve this problem.
If i do it the way it was mentioned on the link, my SecondUsercontrol takes all the Content from the FirstUserControl and i just want to pass the Textboxvalues to the UserControl.

First UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class FirstUserControl: UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public FirstUserControl()
    {
        //this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public string ThemaString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ThemaStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThemaStringProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ThemaString.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThemaStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ThemaString", typeof(string), typeof(sseAnzeigen), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
```

FirstUserControls.xaml:

```
        <Label Content="Thema:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         <TextBox x:Name="ThemaText" Grid.Column="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="8" 
          Text="{Binding ThemaString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
          AncestorType={x:Type local:FirstUserControl}}/>

           <Button Content="Entwurfsansicht" Grid.Row="3"
             Click="Button_Click" />
```

SecondUsercontrol.xaml.cs:

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:FirstUserControl/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
  <TextBlock Text="Thema:" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, 
   ElementName=textBlock, Mode=OneWay}" />
  <TextBox x:Name="ThemaText" Text="{Binding ThemaString}">
```

I tried to cut the code into the pieces of my problem. Hopefully that was good enough to understand what i mean :).
Thank you !!

Comment: Are you attempting to use two way binding?  Or are you just using a button click event to basically do `txtOne.Text = txtTwo.Text`?

Comment: yeah, i actually just want to do   txtOne.Text = txtTwo.Text but i'm not able to get the textbox of the SecondUserControl

Comment: _"i'm not able to get the textbox of the SecondUserControl"_ -- you shouldn't be writing the code in a way that causes you to want to. You haven't provided a [mcve], needed to clearly illustrate your question, but fundamentally the issue here is that you are treating your view objects as the storage for your _data_, which in fact those objects should have only the tasks of _displaying_ your data, or accepting user input which is used to modify your data. The data itself belongs in view model objects, which you can maintain through normal means to copy values as you see fit. Search for "MVVM"

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the wrong minimal example i gave (first post). i did as you mentioned and looked up about MVVM Pattern and created a Viewmodel class, which holds some Data. Furthermore , the datacontext of my Usercontrols are bound to the Viewmodel. Unfortunatly the example data only shows on my FirstUsercontrol in which, i have my Buttonclick event. How can i populate the "Testdata" on my SecondUsercontrol with the ButtonClick event ? Thanks for all the help !